# Can we mock methods also by by using mockito API in junit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit4

I am new to java, for curiosity I am asking, can I mock methods of another classes by using mockito, or only the classes I can mock. thanks in advance

Comment: Please check guidelines before asking, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question is unclear. Of course you can mock other classes.

Comment: Question is interpreted pretty badly. You asking if you can mock methods of another classes or what ? Btw. you can mock any classes  even independently of junit

Comment: Yes that is what I am exactly asking!!